# When citing a book (Harvard) what should year be?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I always see tutorials on Harvard referencing saying things like:

> Last name, First initial. (Year published). *Title*. Edition. City published: Publisher, Page(s).

What do I need to put for year published?

Is that the year of the book's first publication, or the year that the copy I have was published.

---

Specifically, I am trying to cite a translation of *A Doll's House*.

It was originally published (in its original language) in 1879.

This translation was first published in Great Britain in 1994. Reprinted 1999, 2001, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2008, 2009 (twice)

Its ISBN number is 978 1 85459 236 1

Comment: As always, I highly encourage anyone looking to manually create a citation to instead consider investing in a (free) reference manager like Zotero. Let the software figure out the fancy formatting so you can focus on the content :)

Comment: Cite the copyright year

Comment: It is a literary piece, not a reference. In many cases you do not even need to cite it, but if you do you either refer to specific translation or the book itself. If the later, original publishing year is good.

Comment: *Originally published* is not *translation published* is not *reprinted*. What do you think is important?

Comment: @tonysdg but those will still always ask you for the "year" (whatever that means,) unless it's an automatic one that does it by ISBN for example, but using this ISBN number in different generators yields different results.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?

Comment: @theonlygusti probably because it's very easy to look up. Actually the answer is already in your question. (see below)

Comment: @henning but I had been looking it up and couldn't find anything. As I said, all I found were tutorials and guides saying that the way to reference was to put "year."

Comment: @theonlygusti Your example says "year published".

Comment: @Sverre copyright year doesn't always equal publication year.

Comment: @Karl You cite the year of the edition that you are using, not the original publication year; however, you can provide the original date in addition, separating it with square parentheses or a slash.

Comment: @tonysdg Always double-check the metadata that is automatically extracted by reference manager software, especially when you cite books.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56175/discussion-between-henning-and-theonlygusti).

Comment: @henning Editions are published, reprints usually not.

Answer (score 2):

You write down the year in which the particular book that you are holding in your hands was published -- not any earlier or later reprints, not the first publication.

Since you are citing a literary work, and since that work has been republished many times, the date of its publication is not very meaningful. You may be better off using an author-title format (MLA) rather than an author-date format (Harvard).

Comment: Why does Sverre say "cite the copyright year"?

Comment: @theonlygusti I don't know and I wouldn't do it. The copyright year does not always equal the publication year.

Comment: @theonlygusti The most important reason is that it is the copyright year that will normally appear in library databases. And because it is the most common practice. Henning's answer is a good example of how tricky it gets when you try to apply some other practice. "Cite the year it was published, not later reprints". Well, uh - aren't reprints published? Just cite the copyright year and don't worry about it any further.

Comment: @Sverre "the copyright year that will normally appear in library databases" - how do you know library databases don't show the year when the book was published? After all, that's what "publication year" literally means. "aren't reprints published?" - yes, and therefore they have a different publication year. Being able to distinguish between reprints is another reason to stick to the publication year.

Comment: I think I'm at a loss at understanding now what you mean by "publication year". But I don't think it's worth while to keep this discussion going.